# How to link pointer to a std::vector element

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to link a pointer to one of the data member of an std vector.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(5);
    int *ip = &vec[2];
    std::cout << *ip << std::endl;
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + 1); 
    std::cout << *ip << std::endl;
    while (!_kbhit())
    {


    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

The issue which i am facing is that whenever i delete a data element from the vector the pointer than points to another data member.

How can i make a pointer to point at the same data member even after the vector resizes ?

Comment: Don't use a pointer; use an index.

Comment: @WhozCraig wouldn't the index have the same problem, because the element is deleted from the start of the vector?

Comment: @mfnx yes than pointer will point to the new member located at index 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `std::list` instead, which has the sometimes-useful property that iterators and pointers to values contained within are not invalidated upon insertion or deletion of other elements.

If you want integer indexing, use `std::map<int, int>` instead.  Like `std::list` it is a node-based container which does not invalidate iterators or pointers upon insertion or deletion of other elements.  You can emulate `vector::push_back()` like this:

```
void push_back(std::map<int, int>& to, int value) {
    int index = to.empty() ? 0 : ((--to.end())->first + 1);
    to.emplace(index, value);
}
```